# Why does emulation have to be done in real time?

Tags: architecture, binary, emulation, cpu

I understand what an emulator does, changing one machine language into another, often "Just-in-time."  Could such a program be built in that it reads in a binary that is written for one architecture and saves a new binary for another architecture.  After the process completes, it would leave the user with binary ready for native execution on the given architecture.  This would be especially useful for those that have expensive proprietary applications for a legacy architecture.

Is it possible to make such an application?  Binary recompilation is not a new concept, but I have yet to find any useful implementations of such.

With the help of some others, I would be thrilled to start coding on an open source implementation of such a program, if the programming of such is a possibility.

Comment: It's been done a few times. For example, DEC's FX!32 recompiled x86 binaries to run on a DEC Alpha, often faster than any x86 of the time could. It wasn't enough to make up for DEC's (mis)management though, and Compaq/HP didn't care much about it.

Comment: Why do emulators even exist if it's the case?  Is this REALLY *that* much harder than writing an emulator?

Answer (score 10):

*Static recompilation* is a promising way of translating binaries from a foreign architecture to another target architecture. It would be faster than Just-In-Time (JIT), because it doesn't have to compile the code right before running, and because the extra compilation time it could take is useful to optimize the generate code.

However JIT compilation uses dynamic program analysis, while static recompilation relies on static program analysis (hence the name).

In static analysis, you don't have runtime information on an execution.

A major problem with this is posed by indirect jumps. The term covers code that might be generated from certain `switch` statements, from the use of function pointers or from runtime polymorphism (think virtual table).
It all boils down to an instruction of the form:

```
JMP reg_A
```

Let's say you know the start address of your program, and you decided start to recompile instructions from this point. When you encounter a direct jump, you go to its target address, and you continue the recompilation from there. When you encounter an indirect jump though, you're stuck.
In this assembly instruction, the content of `reg_A` is not known statically.
Therefore, we don't know the address of the next instruction. Note that in dynamic recompilation, we don't have this problem, because we emulate the virtual state of the registers, and we know the current content of `reg_A`. Besides, in static recompilation, you are interested in finding **all** possible values for `reg_A` at this point, because you want to have all possible paths compiled. In dynamic analysis, you only need the current value to generate the path that you're currently executing, should `reg_A` change its value, you would still be able to generate the other paths.
In some cases, static analysis can find a list of candidates (if it is a `switch` there must be a table of possible offset somewhere), but in the general case we simply don't know.

*Fine*, you say, *let's recompile all instructions in the binary then!*

The problem here is that in most binaries contain both code and data.
Depending on the architecture, you might not be able to tell which is which.

Worse, in some architectures there are no alignment constraints and variable width instructions, and you may start to dissassemble at some point, only to discover that you've started you recompilation with an offset.

Let's take a simplified instruction set comprising two instructions and a single register `A`:

```
41 xx (size 2): Add xx to `A`.
42 (size 1): Increment `A` by one.
```

Let's take the following binary program:

```
41 42
```

Let's say the start point is the first byte `41`.
You do:

```
 41 42 (size 2): Add 42 to `A`.
```

But what if 41 is a piece of data? Then your program becomes:

```
 42 (size 1): Increment `A` by one.
```

This problem is magnified in old games, which were often optimised directly in assembly, and where the programmer might intentionally [expect some byte to be interpreted as both code and data, depending on the context!](http://andrewkelley.me/post/jamulator.html#dirty-assembly-tricks)

*Even worse*, the recompiled program could be generating code itself! Imagine recompiling a JIT compiler. The result would still output code for the source architecture and try to jump to it, most likely causing the program to die very soon. Statically recompiling code that is only available at runtime requires infinite trickery!

Static binary analysis is a very live area of research (mainly in the field of security, to look for vulnerabilities in systems whose sources are not available), and actually I know of an attempt to produce a [NES emulator that tries to statically recompile programs](http://andrewkelley.me/post/jamulator.html). 
The article is very interesting.

A compromise between JIT and static recompilation would be to statically recompile as much code as possible, keeping only the bits that cannot be translated statically.

Comment: Great explanation. I'd like to mention another possible compromise between static/dynamic recompilation — caching (to a file) of dynamically recompiled code chunks. Perhaps this approach would reap much of the benefit of static recompilation, enhanced by the 'code path discovery' ability of runtime analysis.

Comment: @Cauterite Dynamic recompilation with caching is how the various iterations of Apple's Rosetta work and that's, for example, why PowerPC macs were able to get such good performance when running Motorola 68k applications but you might see them sluggish initially while the cache is getting built up. It's a technique that originated in a little-known product Apple sold mostly to academia during the period Steve Jobs wasn't at Apple named [Macintosh Application Environment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEkSI8yI5_I) for Solaris and HP-UX.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for static vs dynamic recompilation. Dynamic recompilation is what you describe as "real-time" emulation, or recompliation. The code is recompiled in blocks which allows the emulator to accurately reflect the run-time environment of the original code.

Static recompilation is what you are asking if it is possible. It is possible in many different situations as some have pointed out, however code that expects very specific run-time constraints may not run successfully after a static recompilation. This is why Corn,  an N64 Emulator that used static recompilation, can only run a very few highly hand optimized games, while other N64 emulators that employ dynamic recompilation run a much wider variety of games.

Static recompilation is indeed possible for even more complex and traditional code (ie x86 to PowerPC), however such an undertaking would prove extremely tedious, as the recompiler would have to use alot of tricks to get the produced static code to run reliably on the target machine. Dynamic recompilers can do this on the fly at run time at a fraction of the development effort, and for a negligible cost in performance.

Comment: Also I believe there are differences between floating point implementation in different architectures but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to start off by making sure any referenced libraries are re-compiled using this as well.

It's possible, but a huge undertaking.

Also consider there might be licensing issues by doing this; you're creating derivate work based on the original software.  Most license that allow you to do this, will also let you have the source, so you'd be able to just re-compile, or port the source, which is way easier.

Comment: So, this would not be exactly counted as reverse engineering, would it?  I'd love to make such a beast just so there'd be some sort of precedent in the courts.

A useful application would be running closed source PPC binaries on a OS X Mountain Lion, where many of the required lib's are in the OS or could be ported from Snow Leopard or Lion.  Another would be console emulation, where most of the lib's are in the game.

Comment: Not really, your re-compiler would: "read->translate->write new version".  This sounds a lot more like derivative-work than reverse engineering.  Reverse engineering is **understanding** what it does, and writing new code that does the same.

Comment: A useful application would be running closed source PPC binaries on a OS X Mountain Lion, where many of the required lib's are in the OS or could be ported from Snow Leopard or Lion. Another would be console emulation, where most of the lib's are in the game.

Would I get in legal trouble?

Comment: If the author goes after you, probably.  I'm no lawyer though, I've merely read a lot about this.  You should consult a lawyer on this if you're going to put any serious work into something like this.

Comment: Thanks!

How much harder is this than, say, an emulator?

Comment: I really can't say, both are really way out of my scope :)